# while True loop breaking before doing the code (Python 3)

Tags: python

Here is the code, I'm not sure what to do. I have tried as many things as I can find. All the other ones work. My friend has the same problem. We have worked out that it is always the last one. I am using Python 3.

```
score = 0

print("Question 1")
print("What is 'risk'?")
print("A")
print("A safe bet")
print("B")
print("A fried snack")
print("C")
print("A situation involving exposure to danger")
print("Pick Answer Now (A, B or C)")
while True:
 quOne = input()
 if quOne == "a":
  print("Incorrect")
  break
  if quOne == "b":
     print("Incorrect")
     break
     if quOne == "c":
       print("Correct")
       score = (score+1)
       if quOne == "c":
        break

print("Question 2")
print("How do you calculate financial risk?")
```

Comment: Are you testing for `quOne == "b"` *under the condition* that `quOne == "a"`...?

Comment: Is this identation right? Whis is `if quOne =='c'` inside the statement `if quOne == 'b' ` ?

Answer (score 3):

Logic in while is incorrect

```
while True:
 quOne = input()
 if quOne == "a":
  print("Incorrect")
  break
 if quOne == "b":
  print("Incorrect")
  break
 if quOne == "c":
  print("Correct")
  score = (score+1)
  break
```

and an over-simplified version:

```
quOne = input()
if quOne == "c":
 print("Correct")
 score += 1
else:
 print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: thanks. I am new to python so sometimes make those mistakes. I am using sections from old code where I had to make it like that. thanks

Comment: Note that your 'more succint' solution accepts arbitrary input and marks it as incorrect, while the original loop continues to wait for valid input.

Comment: This structure `if quOne == "c": .... else ...` does not allow distinction between a valid (although incorrect) answer "a" and an invalid answer "x" or "1111hm". Probably that's the reason of the whole `while True`, too–to wait until the responder enters a valid response.

Comment: @Joost I changed from *succinct* to *over-simplified*.

Comment: It is working now with syntax, but it is still doing the same problem where the correct answer is not doing the code and adding points. It is justmoving on to the next question

Comment: Yes, the over-simplified version is only a demo, to maintain initial logic, you need to use *while* version

Answer (score 0):

The code is indented wrong.

the second and third "if" statements can only be run after the "break" statements. Also the "while True" doesn't need to be there as the code will wait for the input before proceeding.

```
  if quOne == "a":
     print("Incorrect")
     break
  if quOne == "b":
     print("Incorrect")
     break
  if quOne == "c":
     print("Correct")
     score = (score+1)
     break
```

Should work better. Although you should maybe use if, elif, else, rather than breaks.